# Decomposition group of infinite index?

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

While reading Neukirch's book *"Algebraic Number Theory"* I found the following observation (pg. 170):

> The decomposition group $G_w$ controls the extension of $v$ to $L$ in a group-theoretic manner. Denoting by $G_w\setminus G$ the set of all right cosets $G_w\sigma,$ by $W_v$ the set of extensions of $v$ to $L$ and choosing a fixed extension $w,$ we obtain a bijection $$G_w\setminus G \rightarrow W_v, \ G_w\sigma \mapsto w\circ \sigma.$$ In particular, the number $\# W_v$ of extensions equals the index $(G:G_w).$

I'm interested in the last part of this text.

We are supossing that the extension $(k,v) \subset (L,w)$ of valued fields is **Galois** (with this notation I mean that $w$ is an absolute value extending $v.)$ When the extension $L | k$ is of finite degree the mentioned result is well known.

My problem is that once I suppose the extension $L|k$ of **infinite degree**, I'm not sure about the statement. It's well known that the decomposition group $G_w$ is closed in the Krull topology but the index $(G:G_w)$ may be infinite (I can't prove its finiteness). Also, if this index is finite then the group $G_w$ would be open for the Krull topology. For sure, there are examples of decomposition groups that are open (for example, assuming $k$ to be complete with respect to $v$ since the decomposition group coincides with the whole group) but I can't figure out an example of a decomposition group that's not open.

So I'd appreciate any examples of non-open decomposition groups or any information about the topological properties of decomposition groups.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question fits better here or at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)...

Comment: It's decomposition, I wrote it wrong many times since in Spanish the term is "descomposición".

Comment: That's what I thought – some *lapsus calami* (which also happen to me!)

Comment: Example 1: Let $F/\mathbf{Q}$ be an imaginary quadratic field, and let $H/F$ be an anti-cyclotomic $\mathbf{Z}_p$-extension, so that $H/\mathbf{Q}$ is Galois with Galois group the infinite "dihedral" extension $\Gamma:=\mathbf{Z}_p \rtimes \mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z}$. If the prime $q$ is inert in $F/\mathbf{Q}$, then the image of Frobenius in $\Gamma/\mathbf{Z}_p = \mathbf{Z}/2 \mathbf{Z} = \mathrm{Gal}(F/\mathbf{Q})$ has order $2$. But all preimages of this element in  $\Gamma$ have order $2$. Hence the decomposition group has order $2$ inside the infinite group $\Gamma$.

Comment: Example 2: Let $E/\mathbf{Q}$ be an elliptic curve without CM, and let $H/\mathbf{Q}$ be the field obtained by adjoining all the $p^n$-torsion points for all $n$. Then $\mathrm{Gal}(H/\mathbf{Q})$ is a finite index subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$, and all but finitely many primes are unramified in this extension. But the decomposition group $D$ of such a prime (since $q$ is unramified) will be a pro-cyclic subgroup which always has infinite indext inside $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$.

Comment: Thanks @user902362 for your examples. I don't know enough to understand correctly your comments. Anyway, thanks for your time. Could you provide some references about the anti-cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension? It's the first time I hear it...